# What do I do with this error when I run tests in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

using ruby1.9.2 rails3.1.0

I am working from my netbook, so it is not my usual dev environment. I cloned a repo that I was working with on my desktop early this week. Now when I run `rake test` I get this error in the terminal.

```
^[[1;5C/home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53: warning: already initialized constant WFKV_
/home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/turn-0.8.3/lib/turn/autorun/minitest.rb:14:in `<top (required)>': MiniTest v1.6.0 is out of date. (RuntimeError)
`gem install minitest` and add `gem 'minitest' to you test helper.
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/turn-0.8.3/lib/turn.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/test_help.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/work/Desktop/sa_clubbing/test/test_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/work/Desktop/sa_clubbing/test/unit/blog_post_test.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/work/Desktop/sa_clubbing/test/unit/blog_post_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `each'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `<main>'
/home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53: warning: already initialized constant WFKV_
/home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/turn-0.8.3/lib/turn/autorun/minitest.rb:14:in `<top (required)>': MiniTest v1.6.0 is out of date. (RuntimeError)
`gem install minitest` and add `gem 'minitest' to you test helper.
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/turn-0.8.3/lib/turn.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/test_help.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/work/Desktop/sa_clubbing/test/test_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/work/Desktop/sa_clubbing/test/functional/landing_page_controller_test.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/work/Desktop/sa_clubbing/test/functional/landing_page_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `require'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `each'
    from /home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `<main>'
Errors running test:units, test:functionals!
```

I followed the instruction and did `gem install minitest` , but still get the same result. Anyone know what to do here?

I just checked my gem list and it says minitest version 2.6.2 is installed. I don't know why the error is saying `MiniTest v1.6.0 is out of date` I am not using that version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bundle exec rake test
```

Having a `.rvmrc` file in the project's root directory is handy for automatically setting the correct ruby/gemset. Also make sure your Gemfile/Gemfile.lock are using the correct version.

Comment: I didn't have it in my gem file. I do have it installed in my gemset though. I guess you have to specify it in the Gemfile.

Comment: @SpencerCooley Yep! Preferably in the dev and test scope only.

Comment: That's because `bundle exec` will scope your gems to just what's in `Gemfile.lock`

Answer (score 8):

I fixed it in the following way:
add in your Gemfile following gem, Then run bundle install

```
group :test do
  gem 'turn', '< 0.8.3'
end
```

Comment: Or remove "turn" gem completely if you don't use MiniTest and use something like RSpec instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to fix it...
go to the root of your aplication and type:
    **gem install minitest**
Then go to your gemfile located in the root of your app and add
    **gem 'minitest'** at the bottom of the file.